# How can I find out the number of consumers of a queue in a clustered HornetQ environment?

Tags: java, queue, hornetq

Without clustering (multiple number of active HornetQ servers connected), I used the following code, to get to know the number of consumers of a queue:

```
ClientSession.QueueQuery result;
result = session.queueQuery(new SimpleString(queueName));
count = result.getConsumerCount();
```

However, if I use a clustered setup with multiple active HornetQ server that are connected to each other, each server will only return the consumers that are connected to itsself only but not to other servers.

How can I get the number of consumers that are also connected to other servers?